# PHP extension compilation for linux

Tags: php, php-extension

Is it possible to compile php extension on one linux distro, such as Ubuntu( or other debian) and use same compiled extension on centos?

I want to distribute an extension with my application, is there any way for me to compile it such that once compiled, it can work on all linux distros?

Comment: I believe it is practically not easily possible (e.g. dependency to the version of GNuLibc, ....). It is much better to distribution your extension as a free software in source form. (and there might be licensing reasons to do so).

Comment: distributing source and asking to compile it will make it hard for end users to get application working

Comment: The make it free software, so give the source code and package it for some few Linux distributions. Other distributions could package it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, As extension can have different dependencies depend on Distro, So there will always be chances that your compiled extension will have problems on other distro. You just ready your source code. So anybody can compiled on their distro using standard extension compilation process.